# does whitespace in a file or filename matter for calculating checksum

Tags: file, unix, checksum

does whitespace in a file or filename matter for calculating checksum for a file? So if i am calculating the checksum, shall i remove the whitespaces from the file and filename too?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Changes in whitespace would change the checksum of the data, but I don't see why you would want to strip the whitespace from your data.

Comment: i have used shasums for checking file intigrity, but it breaks when i have whitespaces and $ in my filenames. What can i do here?

Comment: You should probably post some code of your SHA calculation, as it does not make sense the way you have described it. A file's name is not a part of its data and should not affect the SHA sum of the file contents.

Answer (score 0):

The most common Unix utilities for calculating hashes and checksums for files, such as `md5sum`  or `sha256sum`, do not do anything special w.r.t. their input files. Therefore, the input files are considered to contain random binary data; every single byte of content is taken into account, regardless of whether it is whitespace or not.

On the other hand, the file *names* are not taken into account at all when calculating a hash for the *contents* of the file.

We might be able to help you more if you mentioned the actual problem that you are trying to solve...

Comment: i am using shasums for checking a file's integrity. but it breaks if there are whitespaces or $ in filenames. how can i overcome this?

Comment: @PinkySharma: that is a general issue with the shell command line - some characters need to be escaped: `$` is the character that indicates variable names, while whitespace separates arguments. You need to *quote* your filenames. For most Unix shells, you can surround the filename with single quotes to avoid surprises: `sha1sum 'name with $& e.t.c.'`